# How to align the Header Row contents of a Markdown table to Left and all the other rows contents to Right with a PYTHON code

Tags: python, csv, format, markdown

I have a CSV file (summary.csv) and I have written a python script to convert this CSV file to a markdown file (summary.md) to get the results in the CSV file to a markdown table. In the markdown table I want to align only the header row (row with headings) contents to Left and all the other rows contents to Right. I used the code given [here](https://gist.github.com/csmoore/10802656). How to incorporate this to the below code section in [1](https://gist.github.com/csmoore/10802656)?

```
mdSeparator = '|'
justifyEntry = '---'  # =Left - or- :---: (center) -or- ---: (Right)
rowCount = 0
for row in reader:
    colCount = 0
    line = mdSeparator
    for col in row:
        line += col
        line += mdSeparator  # add '|'
        colCount += 1

    line += '\n'
    outputFile.write(line)

    if rowCount == 0:

        # If this is the 1st/header row, add a 2nd row with "|---|---|..."

        line = mdSeparator
        for headerCount in range(0, colCount):
            line += justifyEntry
            line += mdSeparator
        line += '\n'
        outputFile.write(line)

    rowCount += 1
```

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the question to add a small example CSV file, and the output you are trying to get for it.

Comment: You don't mention which Markdown table implementation you are using. Regardless, I am not aware of any which support aligning the header row separate from the body rows. In other words, the alignment always applies to an entire column. For anything beyond that, you would need to use CSS to style the HTML output.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the provided solution and was able to get a understanding on how I need to proceed to achieve this. Thanks :)